# best approach to navigate pages in react js

Tags: reactjs, navigation

Hope you are doing well!
I found different ways of navigating in React Js.
For example
Using Link, NavLink, Redirect Component, `history.push`, and `history.replace`.
I am a bit confused, about which method is perfect or recommended. Thanks.

Comment: Each of those elements you lists serve a different purpose or usecase. It also depends on your requirements, and which routing/navigation library/package you are using. Do you have a more specific question or issue? This is too open, broad, and off-topic. If you are asking for recommendations, this is also off-topic. Asking superlatively quantified questions is also generally off-topic as they tend to be opinionated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a new learner, you only need to know `<Route>`, `<Switch>`, and `<Link>`. And also `<Link>` and `<a>` difference. The rest you mentioned comes with intermediate level React. So, I kindly advise you to take it bit by bit and also try to make your questions more to the point as editor noted in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to React as well and I think using any sort of Link/Navlink along with the Switch Route is a good way. It helps me sort of modularize the routing, no matter where the path changes from.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).